# I can see env variable on server using printenv, but cannot get them in php

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, environment-variables

I'd like to use certain env variables in my app, and when I try to get it

```
printenv | grep "MY_VARIABLE"
```

I get it out

```
MyVariable
```

But when I try to get it in php

```
print_r( getenv( 'MY_VARIABLE' ) );
```

I don't get anything out.

I'm using EC2 instance on AWS, not sure if this helps.

I also tried with `$_SERVER` and `$_ENV` but nothing...

Comment: Are you running the app via the same command line you have executed printenv, or is the app run via a webserver/php stack?

Comment: app is run via a webserver.

Comment: When you are running the command, do you mean within a shell? What user is that shell running as? What about the user for the webservice process (apache or otherwise)? How has the environment variable your looking for been set?

Comment: The env variables weren't configured in the php fpm pool, this is why I couldn't access them using `getenv`.

Comment: That sounds like you should add it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The env variables weren't configured in the PHP fpm pool, this is why I couldn't access them using `getenv`.

However, this is not the most secure way to store the environment variables. Be sure to disable `phpinfo()` on your server if you are using them.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try first to use the phpinfo() function to find out if the requested value is set!
or try to set the local_only value to true.